# Setting request header content-type to json in Spring Framework resttemplate

Tags: spring, rest, content-type, resttemplate

I'm learning Spring Framework to create a client of a REST web service that uses basic authentication and exchanges JSON.  After much searching on the web, I wrote some code that worked (below), but now I'm getting an "Unsupported Media Type" error because the requests are sent with Content-Type text/plain rather than application/json.  I've found nothing on the web that shows how to set Content-Type in the request header (without getting completely lost in the weeds).  My code is:

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

...

BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("login", "password"));
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
String url = "http://host:8080/path/";
String postBody = getPostInput("filename");
jsonString = restTemplate.postForObject(path, postBody, String.class);
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
George

Comment: I realized that some of the code is not correct.  I was sending a POST request with a JSON body.  Here's the correct code.

Comment: I edited the original question to correct the code.  Still learning how to use stackoverflow...

Comment: does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263854/java-httpclient-changing-content-type

Answer (score 125, accepted):

you can try using any method from below code

**1**

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(postBodyJson ,headers);
restTemplate.put(uRL, entity);
```

**2**

```
RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = RequestEntity .post(new URL(attributeLookupUrl).toURI()) .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) .body(postBodyJson); 
restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, responseClass);
```

**3**

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

// if you need to pass form parameters in request with headers.
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("username", userName);
map.add("password", password);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
ResponseEntity<TokenVO> responses = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, request, responseClass);
```

Comment: This may be a new function, but you can now also do the following:
    RequestEntity<String> requestEntity =
                RequestEntity
                    .post(new URL(attributeLookupUrl).toURI())
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(postBodyJson);
    restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, responseClass);