Twilio SDK overriding the default behavior of RestTemplate
Twilio SDK overriding RestTemplate behavior to send body as XML:
i have legacy code in multiple places where using restTemplate to send external request as the following:
RestTemplate remote = new RestTemplate();
remote.postForObject(url, entity);

and it was working as expected before including Twilio SDK and sending the body as JSON, now it sent as XML and the request refused in multiple places:
"Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"`

i tried to exclude faster-xml lib in pom.xml file and not working
and tries to get ResTemplate as autowired: it worked but then we need a huge change in the legacy code!

You shouldn’t rely on default content type to be json, just define content type explicitly in entity as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417455/setting-request-header-content-type-to-json-in-spring-framework-resttemplate
