# Change content type from Java url request

Tags: java, json

I am learning Java and JSON parsing.

I have this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ParseJsonFaculties
{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String url = "https://somesite/";
                try {
                        String facultiesJson = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), "default");
                        JSONObject facultiesJsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(facultiesJson);
                        // get id.
                        JSONArray facultiesArrayId = (JSONArray) facultiesJsonObject.get("Id");
                        // get name.
                        JSONArray facultiesArrayName = (JSONArray) facultiesJsonObject.get("Name");
                        // get get shortname.
                        JSONArray facultiesArrayShortname = (JSONArray) facultiesJsonObject.get("ShortName");
                        // output.
                        System.out.print(facultiesArrayId + " ");
                        System.out.print(facultiesArrayName + " ");
                        System.out.print(facultiesArrayShortname);
                } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

But this returns a XML instead of JSON.

And something like this from terminal:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://univeris.susu.ru/services/mobile/Faculties
```

Actually returns JSON string.

So how to change content type in this code? Thanks!

Comment: Tou have to change your Content-Type . I dnt know how your URL class looks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263854/java-httpclient-changing-content-type

Comment: Since you're already using an Apache library, you should consider using [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) for better handling of the HTTP communication, e.g. for setting the `Accept` HTTP Header you're missing. But, you can also just use the Java built-in [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), instead of just the simple `URL` you're doing right now.